# How to inject remote CSS file onto current tab? [Chrome Extension Manifest V3]

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Does anyone know how to inject a remote CSS file onto current tab without downloading it and adding to my extension package?

Here's the code I'm running:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs)
{
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.scripting.insertCSS
    ({
        target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
        files: ['https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Acme']
    });         
    chrome.scripting.insertCSS
    ({
        target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
        css: 'body{font-family:Acme !important;}'
    });         
});
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not load file: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Acme'.

Here's sections of the manifest I've added without luck:

```
"host_permissions": 
[
    "https://fonts.googleapis.com",
    "https://fonts.gstatic.com"
],    
"web_accessible_resources": 
[
    {
      "resources": [ "css2?family=Acme" ],
      "matches": [ "https://fonts.googleapis.com/*" ]
    },
    {
      "resources": [ "MwQ5bhbm2POE2V9BPQ.woff2" ],
      "matches": [ "https://fonts.gstatic.com/*" ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one workaround for my problem that actually gives me the result I'm looking for by storing the content of the remote CSS file into a string first. It's a bit hacky and relies on jQuery. Would still like to find a better way.

```
$.ajax
({
    type:'GET',
    url:'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Acme',
    success: function(fontCss)
    {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs)
        {
            var activeTab = tabs[0];
            var customCss = 'body{font-family:Acme !important;}';
            var fullCss = fontCss + customCss;                
            chrome.scripting.insertCSS
            ({
                target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
                css: fullCss
            });        
        });            
    }
});
```

Comment: @wOxxOm Is this for manifest v3 only? Does this mean AJAX requests to remote resources are not allowed as well? In developer mode, it's working fine. Also, I've seen some extensions that definitely inject remote resources onto a page one way or another.

Comment: @wOxxOm Also, from what I read, remote scripts are forbidden from being injected on the page for security reasons, but I haven't read anything about HTML or CSS being forbidden.

Comment: You're right, they don't enforce it yet for MV2.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the replies. I might have wasted days of coding for nothing assuming you're right. The documentation is really ambiguous in a lot of areas. My extension is working great in developer mode without errors so assumed it would pass inspection.

Comment: @wOxxOm Just to follow up with this. I submitted the extension for publishing to the web store and it was approved already. I haven't actually published it because it's not 100% done.

Comment: The quick approvals on CWS may be semi-automated so the problem may still arise when the extension finally reaches a human review.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is there such a step? once the webstore approves it I think that's the end of the journey. You are ready to publish it basically. Am I correct?

Comment: There must be, since they can't physically perform human review on all extensions quickly.